# Printing binary values in Java

Tags: java

Why the output of this java program is `8` and `9` while we try to print `010` and `011` respectively:

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String str[]){ 
      System.out.println(011); 
   }
}
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Can you show us your code?  We have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: public class Test{
public static void main(String str[]){
System.out.println(011);
}}

Answer (score 6):

`010` is interpretetion of `10` in octal base which is `8`. And similarly `011` is interpretetion of `11` in `octal base` which is `9`.

Prepending an `integer` with `0` makes it interpreted in `octal base`.

Similarly, you can try printing `0x10`, which is a `hexadecimal` representation, and will give you `16` as output.

Comment: Thank U Rohit Jain for ur help

Answer (score 6):

In Java, the default conversion from integer to string is base 10. If you want a different radix, you have to specify it explicitly. For instance, you can convert an integer value to a binary string using:

```
Integer.toString(value, 2);
```

Similarly, you can convert it to an octal value with:

```
Integer.toString(value, 8);
```

Unless the value is 0, the string will not have a leading zero. If you want a leading 0, you'll have to prepend it. Alternatively, you can format it with [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and specify zero fill and a minimum width for the converted string:

```
String.format("%1$03o", value); // the "1$ in the format string is optional here
```

P.S. It's not clear from your question what the exact problem is. It sounds like it's that you are converting from an integer value to a string. However, if the problem is that you're trying to read the string "011" and it is being read as the integer value 9, this is because a leading 0 forces interpretation as an octal value. You'll have to read it as a String value and then explicitly specify the conversion from string to integer to be base 10:

```
int val = Integer.valueOf(stringValue, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

**-** If you want to convert the integer to binary data, use `toBinaryString()` method.

**Eg:**

```
int i = 8;
Integer.toBinaryString(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

bec. when you start your number with 0 JVM convert the number from decimal to octal that's all ;)
"11 in decimal = 9 in octal"
decimal 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9
octal   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 11